# Efficient way to divide a list into lists of n size

Tags: java, arraylist, partitioning

I have an `ArrayList`, which I want to divide into smaller `List` objects of `n` size, and perform an operation on each.
My current method of doing this is implemented with `ArrayList` objects in Java. Any pseudocode will do.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= Math.floor((A.size() / n)); i++) {
            ArrayList temp = subArray(A, ((i * n) - n),
                    (i * n) - 1);
            // do stuff with temp
        }

    private ArrayList<Comparable> subArray(ArrayList A, int start,
                int end) {
            ArrayList toReturn = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                toReturn.add(A.get(i));
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
```

where `A` is the list and `n` is the size of the desired lists

I believe this way is taking too much time when working with considerably large lists of up to 1 million in size, so I'm trying to figure out what would be more efficient.

Comment: [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) is a mystery.

Comment: For java 8 here is a sample article along with the performace of each method: https://e.printstacktrace.blog/divide-a-list-to-lists-of-n-size-in-Java-8/

Comment: Please stop using *toReturn*. It has no meaning. Might as well use *r* or *x*. Name it "partition" or "shard" or something meaningful.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You'll want to do something that makes use of [List.subList(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) views rather than copying each sublist. To do this really easily, use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [Lists.partition(List, int)](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) method:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
for (List<Foo> partition : Lists.partition(foos, n)) {
  // do something with partition
}
```

Note that this, like many things, isn't very efficient with a `List` that isn't `RandomAccess` (such as a `LinkedList`).

Comment: There is also `Iterables.partition(Iterable, int)` if you have an `Iterable` instead of a `List`

Comment: The last link has changed, I think is this one https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List, int)

Comment: I have a quick question about lists.partition what happens if the input list size is less than the expected size of sublist. Does this method handle that or client needs to validate that?

Comment: @user506591: Updated the Javadoc link. The last list in the partition can be smaller than the partition size. So in the case where the entire original list is smaller, the partition will contain a single list with all of its elements.

Answer (score 43):

For example:

```
    int partitionSize = 10;
    List<List<String>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<yourlist.size(); i += partitionSize) {
        partitions.add(yourlist.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, yourlist.size())));
    }

    for (List<String> list : partitions) {
        //Do your stuff on each sub list
    }
```

Comment: Definitely best answer

Comment: Thanks for the best solution.

Comment: Well, the moment I feel LeetCode stuff is useful. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

If you are working with a list I use the "[Apache Commons Collections 4](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)" library. It has a partition method in the ListUtils class:

```
...
int targetSize = 100;
List<Integer> largeList = ...
List<List<Integer>> output = ListUtils.partition(largeList, targetSize);
```

This method is adapted from http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to use a library, here's my solution

1.To partition in N equal parts:

```
private <T> List<List<T>> nPartition(List<T> objs, final int N) {
    return new ArrayList<>(IntStream.range(0, objs.size()).boxed().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(e->e%N,Collectors.mapping(e->objs.get(e), Collectors.toList())
                    )).values());
}
```

2. To partition in sets of N items:

```
private <T> List<List<T>> nPartition(List<T> objs, final int N) {
    return new ArrayList<>(IntStream.range(0, objs.size()).boxed().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(e->e/N,Collectors.mapping(e->objs.get(e), Collectors.toList())
                    )).values());
    }
```

In action here:
https://ideone.com/QiQnbE

Answer (score 6):

// Testing data

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2,     3, 4, 5,    6, 7, 8,    9);
int n = 3;
```

**// One line(statement) with java 8 stream and list.subList**

```java
List<List<Integer>> partitions = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> i % n == 0)
    .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i, Math.min(i + n, list.size() )))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

Well i wrote one myself before i saw ColinD's answer (+1) and using Guava is definitely the way to go.  It was too much fun to leave alone and so the below gives you a copy of the list rather than views so GUava's is definitely more efficient than this.  I'm posting this because it was fun to write rather than suggesting it is as efficient:

The Hamcrest test (one of anyway):

```
assertThat(chunk(asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 2), 
           equalTo(asList(asList("a", "b"), asList("c", "d"), asList("e"))));
```

The code:

```
public static <T> Iterable<Iterable<T>> chunk(Iterable<T> in, int size) {
    List<Iterable<T>> lists = new ArrayList();
    Iterator<T> i = in.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList();
        for (int j=0; i.hasNext() && j<size; j++) {
            list.add(i.next());
        }
        lists.add(list);
    }
    return lists;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public <E> Iterable<List<E>> partition(List<E> list, final int batchSize)
{
    assert(batchSize > 0);
    assert(list != null);
    assert(list.size() + batchSize <= Integer.MAX_VALUE); //avoid overflow

    int idx = 0;

    List<List<E>> result = new ArrayList<List<E>>();

    for (idx = 0; idx + batchSize <= list.size(); idx += batchSize) {
        result.add(list.subList(idx, idx + batchSize));
    }
    if (idx < list.size()) {
        result.add(list.subList(idx, list.size()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Java 9
public static <T> List<List<T>> partition(List<T> list, int size) {
    return Stream.iterate(0, i -> i <= list.size(), i -> i + size)
        .map(i -> list.subList(i, Math.min(i + size, list.size())))
        .filter(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty))
        .toList();
}
```

```
testing partition(list, 3)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       > [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]    > [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] > [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]
[1]                   > [[1]]
[]                    > []
```

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented a list partitioning, because I couldn't use a library.

So I want to share my code here:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ListPartitioning<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

  private final List<T> list;
  private final int partitionSize;

  public ListPartitioning(List<T> list, int partitionSize) {
    if (list == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("list must not be null");
    }
    if (partitionSize < 1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("partitionSize must be 1 or greater");
    }
    this.list = list;
    this.partitionSize = partitionSize;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
    return new ListPartitionIterator<T>(list, partitionSize);
  }

  private static class ListPartitionIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>> {

    private int index = 0;

    private List<T> listToPartition;
    private int partitionSize;
    private List<T> nextPartition;

    public ListPartitionIterator(List<T> listToPartition, int partitionSize) {
      this.listToPartition = listToPartition;
      this.partitionSize = partitionSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return index < listToPartition.size();
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> next() {
      if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }

      int partitionStart = index;
      int partitionEnd = Math.min(index + partitionSize, listToPartition.size());

      nextPartition = listToPartition.subList(partitionStart, partitionEnd);
      index = partitionEnd;
      return nextPartition;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      if (nextPartition == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("next must be called first");
      }

      nextPartition.clear();
      index -= partitionSize;
      nextPartition = null;
    }
  }
}
```

And the unit test based on testng.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.*;


public class ListPartitioningTest {

  @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void nullList() {
    ListPartitioning<String> lists = new ListPartitioning<String>(null, 1);
  }

  @Test(groups = Group.UNIT_TEST, expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void wrongPartitionSize() {
    ListPartitioning<String> lists = new ListPartitioning<String>(new ArrayList<String>(), 0);
  }


  @Test()
  public void iteratorTest() {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
    ListPartitioning<Integer> listPartitioning = new ListPartitioning<Integer>(integers, 7);
    Iterator<List<Integer>> partitionIterator = listPartitioning.iterator();
    Assert.assertNotNull(partitionIterator);

    Assert.assertTrue(partitionIterator.hasNext(), "next partition (first)");
    List<Integer> partition = partitionIterator.next();
    Assert.assertEquals(partition, Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

    Assert.assertTrue(partitionIterator.hasNext(), "next partition (second)");
    partition = partitionIterator.next();
    Assert.assertEquals(partition, Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13));

    Assert.assertTrue(partitionIterator.hasNext(), "next partition (third)");
    partition = partitionIterator.next();
    Assert.assertEquals(partition, Arrays.asList(14, 15));

    Assert.assertFalse(partitionIterator.hasNext());
  }

  @Test(expectedExceptions = NoSuchElementException.class)
  public void noSuchElementException() {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1);
    ListPartitioning<Integer> listPartitioning = new ListPartitioning<Integer>(integers, 2);
    Iterator<List<Integer>> partitionIterator = listPartitioning.iterator();
    List<Integer> partition = partitionIterator.next();
    partition = partitionIterator.next();
  }

  @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalStateException.class)
  public void removeWithoutNext() {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15));
    ListPartitioning<Integer> listPartitioning = new ListPartitioning<Integer>(integers, 7);
    Iterator<List<Integer>> partitionIterator = listPartitioning.iterator();
    partitionIterator.remove();
  }

  @Test()
  public void remove() {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15));
    ListPartitioning<Integer> listPartitioning = new ListPartitioning<Integer>(integers, 7);
    Iterator<List<Integer>> partitionIterator = listPartitioning.iterator();

    partitionIterator.next();
    partitionIterator.next();

    partitionIterator.remove();
    Assert.assertTrue(partitionIterator.hasNext(), "next partition ");
    List<Integer> partition = partitionIterator.next();
    Assert.assertEquals(partition, Arrays.asList(14, 15));

    Assert.assertFalse(partitionIterator.hasNext());

    Assert.assertEquals(integers, Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 14, 15));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to optimise your performance you should use a parallel stream instead of a for loop. This way you can use multiple threads.

```
Lists.partition(A, n).parallelStream().forEach({
    //do stuff with temp
});
```

You can also use other ways to work with the stream for example collect or map if it matches your purpose.

Comment: Note that `Lists.partition()` seems to be a Google Guava specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One line using Java 8:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size() / batchSize + 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * batchSize,
                Math.min(i * batchSize + batchSize, list.size())))
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Had I compelled to do this without relying on any 3<sup>rd</sup> party library, I'd go with something like

```java
<T> List<List<T>> partitionList(List<T> src, int maxPartitionSize) {
  final List<List<T>> res = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
    if (i % maxPartitionSize == 0) {
      res.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    res.get(i / maxPartitionSize).add(src.get(i));
  }

  return res;
}
```

Complete example:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListPartitionDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Integer> toPartition = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    System.out.println(partitionList(toPartition, 2));
  }

  // public static <T> List<List<T>> partitionList(List<T> src, int maxPartitionSize) { ... }
}
```

resulting in

```bash
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with arrays, you can use [System.arraycopy()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) for that.

```
 int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};

 int[] b = new int[2];
 int[] c = new int[3];

 System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, 2); // b will be {1,2}
 System.arraycopy(a, 2, c, 0, 3); // c will be {3,4,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to partition a List into an array of sublists, which ensures all but the last sublist have equal number of elements:

```
static <T> List<T>[] split(List<T> source, int numPartitions) {
    if (numPartitions < 2)
        return new List[]{source};

    final int sourceSize = source.size(),
        partitions = numPartitions > sourceSize ? sourceSize: numPartitions,
        increments = sourceSize / partitions;

    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, partitions)
        .mapToObj(i -> source.subList(i*increments, Math.min((i+1)*increments, sourceSize)))
        .toArray(List[]::new);
}
```

If you want to guarantee `numPartitions` array size then you want:

```
static <T> List<T>[] split(List<T> source, int numPartitions) {
    if (numPartitions < 2)
        return new List[]{source};

    final int sourceSize = source.size(),
        partitions = numPartitions > sourceSize ? sourceSize: numPartitions,
        increments = sourceSize / partitions;

    return IntStream.range(0, partitions)
        .mapToObj(i -> source.subList(i*increments, i == partitions-1 ? sourceSize : (i+1)*increments))
        .toArray(List[]::new);
}
```

Comment: `If you want to guarantee numPartitions array size ` What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SubListTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> alphabetNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        // populate alphabetNames array with AAA,BBB,CCC,.....
        int a = (int) 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            char x = (char) (a + i);
            char[] array = new char[3];
            Arrays.fill(array, x);
            alphabetNames.add(new String(array));
        }

        int[] maxListSizes = new int[]
        {
            5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30
        };

        for (int maxListSize : maxListSizes)
        {
            System.out.println("######################################################");
            System.out.println("Partitioning original list of size " + alphabetNames.size() + " in to sub lists of max size "
                + maxListSize);

            ArrayList<List<String>> subListArray = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            if (alphabetNames.size() <= maxListSize)
            {
                subListArray.add(alphabetNames);
            }
            else
            {
                // based on subLists of maxListSize X
                int subListArraySize = (alphabetNames.size() + maxListSize - 1) / maxListSize;
                for (int i = 0; i < subListArraySize; i++)
                {
                    subListArray.add(alphabetNames.subList(i * maxListSize,
                        Math.min((i * maxListSize) + maxListSize, alphabetNames.size())));
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Resulting number of partitions " + subListArray.size());

            for (List<String> subList : subListArray)
            {
                System.out.println(subList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
######################################################
Partitioning original list of size 26 in to sub lists of max size 5
Resulting number of partitions 6
[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE]
[FFF, GGG, HHH, III, JJJ]
[KKK, LLL, MMM, NNN, OOO]
[PPP, QQQ, RRR, SSS, TTT]
[UUU, VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY]
[ZZZ]
######################################################
Partitioning original list of size 26 in to sub lists of max size 10
Resulting number of partitions 3
[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, III, JJJ]
[KKK, LLL, MMM, NNN, OOO, PPP, QQQ, RRR, SSS, TTT]
[UUU, VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY, ZZZ]
######################################################
Partitioning original list of size 26 in to sub lists of max size 15
Resulting number of partitions 2
[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, III, JJJ, KKK, LLL, MMM, NNN, OOO]
[PPP, QQQ, RRR, SSS, TTT, UUU, VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY, ZZZ]
######################################################
Partitioning original list of size 26 in to sub lists of max size 20
Resulting number of partitions 2
[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, III, JJJ, KKK, LLL, MMM, NNN, OOO, PPP, QQQ, RRR, SSS, TTT]
[UUU, VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY, ZZZ]
######################################################
Partitioning original list of size 26 in to sub lists of max size 25
Resulting number of partitions 2
[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, III, JJJ, KKK, LLL, MMM, NNN, OOO, PPP, QQQ, RRR, SSS, TTT, UUU, VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY]
[ZZZ]
######################################################
Partitioning original list of size 26 in to sub lists of max size 30
Resulting number of partitions 1
[AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF, GGG, HHH, III, JJJ, KKK, LLL, MMM, NNN, OOO, PPP, QQQ, RRR, SSS, TTT, UUU, VVV, WWW, XXX, YYY, ZZZ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @BrownRecluse[ response][1], you can implement this method:

```
public HashMap<Integer,Object> splitListInSubLists(List<? extends Object> originalList, Integer sizeSublist){
    HashMap<Integer,Object> sublistHashMap =  new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    if ((originalList!=null) && (sizeSublist!=null)) {
        for (int i=0; i<originalList.size(); i += sizeSublist) {
            sublistHashMap.put(i, (Object) originalList.subList(i, Math.min(i + sizeSublist, originalList.size())));
        }
    }
    return sublistHashMap;
}
```

And this is a example:

```
// Example - Split original List in sublists
List<String> myLongList = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");
        
HashMap<Integer, Object> sublists = splitListInSubLists(myLongList , 3);
            
for (Object sublist : sublists.values()) {// Iterate
    List<String> mySublist= (List<String>) sublist;
       // Your code ...
}

,,, 
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5143356/brownrecluse
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
Arrays.copyOfRange( original, from, to )
```

?

Comment: What about the items after `to`?