# Using streams to partition a set of strings into subsets of size x

Tags: java, stream

I have a stream of strings. I want to provide a method parameter x which then streams the strings in groups of x which can then be collected in a set.

So if x=4 then and the stream size was 8, then I would have two sets containing 4 elements. The for each of those sets of 4 elements I can call ForEach and do other operations on, in the above example forEach would be called twice 1 for each 4 element set.

Comment: Counting stream sizes is a terminal operation.

Comment: Unclear what youre asking but you need to try something before asking a question. This is a Q&A site

Comment: @Reimeus please see the title. I guess I am looking to use streams to partition a set of strings into subsets of size x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824825/efficient-way-to-divide-a-list-into-lists-of-n-size

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if it is what you are asking.

So you have some data (say, integer), and you want to put it into multiple collections, each set have X elements.

Maybe you can use a 2D array? I don't have a JDK on hand so i just writing some pseudo code.
For example:

```
int[][] MyArray = new int[MAX_BUFFER][X]
```

Then you use a while loop

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
While(!instream.empty){
  int t = instream.next;
  MyArray[a][b]=t;
  b++;
  if(b>=X){
    a++;
    b=0;
  }
}
```

I suddenly understand that arraylist of arrays may work better for you.

```
ArrayList<int[]> MyArray = new ArrayList<int[]>()

    int a = 0;
    int temparray= new int[X];
    While(!instream.empty){
      int t = instream.next;
      temparray[a]=t;
      a++;
      if(a>=X){
        a=0;
        MyArray.add(temparray);
      }
    }
    if(a>0){//So there are some data left in the temp array;
      MyArray.add(temparray);
    }
```